# I do not get executable files when installing WRF

Tags: software-installation

I am installing WRF (Weather Research and Forecasting) on Ubuntu 16.04, at a certain step, I should have files like this:

```
wrf.exe (model executable)
real.exe (real data initialization)
ndown.exe (one-way nesting)
tc.exe (for tc bogusing--serial only)
```

But I find them with an `.F` extension like this:

```
convert_em.F   ideal_nmm.F       ndown_em.F  real_nmm.F     wrf.F
depend.common  Makefile          nup_em.F    tc_em.F        wrf_SST_ESMF.F
ideal_em.F     module_wrf_top.F  real_em.F   wrf_ESMFMod.F
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know WRF - but .exe sounds more like windoze.  If you check the files themselves, are the executable? (eg. using `stat` or `file` to view stats or file-types)

Comment: What instructions are you following? Please make the context of your problem clear!

Answer (score 3):

The WRF download is a source tarball, so you have to compile the software before you can use it. Work your way through the instructions at http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compilation_tutorial.php.

Generally, EXE files are for Windows only, unless the software package is using an esoteric naming scheme that puts *.exe onto ELF binaries.

Next time, you should consider supplying a link to the software you're trying to install if you want people to help you.

Comment: Linked content can disappear. Please add the relevant details here.